# Getting LinkedIn throttling limit error for Share

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am creating a LinkedIn Application and I am using `'linkedin_3.2.0.class.php'`. Yesterday I was able to share content/status update by this class. But, today I am getting an error 
'`LinkedIn->fetch(): throttling limit for this user/application has been reached for LinkedIn resource - https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares`'. I have check my API Usage Report and I found that every thing is right.. Here I am sharing screen of API Usage Report :

[image]

I have much throttle then why these stupid error coming..

Guys, if you have any idea then kindly share here.

Answer (score 0):

Update with me:

```
Actually this error comes when user's cross of limit LinkedIn share.
```

**More information:** LinkedIn **[Throttle Limits](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/throttle-limits)**